# Java equals method and encrypted Strings

Tags: java, encryption, equals

I've run into a very strange circumstance and figured I would post here because I have no clue what's wrong. I have developed this android app that involves passwords and I have a user with a saved encrypted AES string saved to a file. When a user logs into the system again with their password I need to see whether it equals the encrypted on already in the file.

So I grabbed it and tried to compare the two strings using the .equals method like always and to my surprise it didn't work.

Here are the two strings: What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated since I don't even have an first step on how to solve this. I also tried compareTo == 0 and it didn't work either.

Thank you very much!!!

The first string is from the file, the second is the encrypted version of the password the user just entered:

```
o0JkTVCBcbZnePszCKp64/cOJx/W/dud/xszfvNjwGk=

o0JkTVCBcbZnePszCKp64/cOJx/W/dud/xszfvNjwGk=
```

Comment: If you could show the code with the equals, we might be able to help you. Otherwise, I don't see anything wrong.

Comment: Did you check that the `String` you're getting from the client doesn't have a trailing `\n` or something of the sort?

Comment: Also, I recommend using a `char[]` instead of a `String` for passwords (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Comment: Also, (1) You shouldn't use AES, since it's reversible--use a hash instead, and (2) salt the hash.

Comment: the first string have CRLF try to trim them

Comment: Those strings are clearly duds :-). Seriously, I've created an answer, but you should heed the advice given to you in the comments. Try and use e.g. PBKDF2 instead of AES.

Comment: @ran Instead of performing all sort of tricks on the base64 encoding, I've written an answer which explains to compare the data *within* the base64 encoding. I think that is more concise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Base64 encoding is used to encode binary data into strings; the base64 string is not the data itself. To compare the data in the strings, first decode it to a byte array, then compare the byte arrays using the utility function in the Java `Arrays` class. This should avoid issues with e.g. white space both in and around the encoding.

Comment: an example would be nice

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for late but it works for me
use  **.trim();** for encrypted String and then compare